# How to get the name of a component object which doesn't support the .Name property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, compact-framework

`MenuItem` and `ColumnHeader` are not derived from `Control`. In the full framework they have their own `.Name` property, but in the compact framework they don't. In Visual Studio the form designer shows a `(Name)` and of course I can access that object using this name in code. But how can I get that name as string at runtime? Is it possible somehow, maybe by an extension method which returns the name?

Background is that I am creating multi language windows mobile applications, and to find the text for all items on a form, I use the name of the control as identifier.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16091/User-Interface-Localization-with-the-Compact-Frame) is someone with the same problem and his solution, but I don't like it because of the additional effort to enter all names a second time in code (and also maintain them on changes), after they were already entered visually in the designer. I had to do it for many existing MenuItems and ColumnHeaders...

```
this.AddMenuToDictionary(this.menuItemOpen, "menuItemOpen");
this.AddMenuToDictionary(this.menuItemExit, "menuItemExit");
```

If there is really no better solution than using such a dictionary, at least I would like to fill it without hard coded strings. Can I do this during initialization of the form using reflection?

Comment: I was going to give you the same solution. Why you don't like it? It's just indexing references.......

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, I answered by editing :)

Comment: Hmm that really sucks. I don't think you can get the _`Name`_ at runtime because that only determines the name of the _variable_ containing it. So I think the dictionary idea is the best way forward. You could wrap it up a bit more nicely using a couple of extension methods but it won't give you much. I started writing an answer using Expressions to remove the magic strings but it looks like that isn't supported either! grrr

Comment: I had similar problem years ago when was doing localization of winforms application. Solution was pretty easy: use their indexes and if you need name, then generate it, to example, `Column + index.ToString()` or if you need *uniqueness*, then add unique container name before that. If you need to get *index from name*, then it's all about parsing index from `string`, shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @Sinatr, yes, that's my current way: for objects having no Name property, I use the Text to generate an identifier.

Comment: @Rhumborl, what do you think of my answer? ;-) I like, telling "it's easy!!" after working a long time on finding a solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the form, and not only the `MenuItem` object itself, it's easy:

```
foreach (FieldInfo fi in form.GetType().GetFields(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
    if (fi.FieldType.Name == "MenuItem")
    {
        var mi = (MenuItem) fi.GetValue(form);
        mi.Text = Translate(fi.ReflectedType.Namespace,
            fi.ReflectedType.Name + '.' + fi.Name, fi.FieldType.Name, mi.Text);
    }
```

Any improvements are very welcome, please comment, or create a better answer.

This could also be done more generally for all controls in a form, or maybe just for components not derived from `Control`. With reflection we don't even have to cast to a specific type (like above), we could just look for existence of a Text property and translate it.

But because I wanted to build the identifier including the hierarchy of submenus, I decided to go back to the Dictionary approach and recursively loop through the items (short pseudocode):

```
Dictionary<Component, string> ComponentNames;

foreach (FieldInfo fi in form.GetType().GetFields(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
    if (fi.FieldType.Name == "MenuItem" || fi.FieldType.Name == "ColumnHeader")
        ComponentNames.Add((Component) fi.GetValue(form), fi.Name);

void Recurse(Menu menu, string strIdentifier) {
    if (ComponentNames.TryGetValue(menu, out strName))
         Translate(strIdentifer += '.' + strName, ref strText);
    foreach (MenuItem mi in menu.MenuItems) Recurse(mi, strIdentifier);
```